# Есть ли пересечение строк

Tags: mysql

Имеются 2 строки (перечисления стран):
`str_1`: FR,RU
`str_2`: US,CA,UK,RU

Страны перечислены просто через запятую.
Надо узнать, есть ли хоть одна страна из `str_1` в `str_2`. В данном случае RU.
Как разбить `str_1` и циклом пройтись на соответствие `FIND_IN_SET(str_2)`?

Comment: Если есть возможность перепроектировать схему базы данных в соответствии с [первой нормальной формой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0), лучше так и сделать, тогда ваша задача отпадёт сама собой.

Comment: @fori1ton, если б была возможность, то так и сделал бы)

Comment: @Regent, надо именно в мускуле. Потому как мне потом нужно фильтровать это дело с пагинацией

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835155/mysql-split-comma-separated-string-into-temp-table
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row
https://gist.github.com/avoidwork/3749973

Comment: Вот как раз `REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1), delim, '')` в качестве имитации `split` и многоэтажный запрос для получения списка результата разбиения и печалят своими объёмами.